# Rails jquery ajax request not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In the view:

```
<div>
  <%= radio_button_tag :profile_set, "Profile picture", true, onClick: "set_profile(#{picturething.id});" %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function set_profile(picid) {
    alert("Hello.");
    $.ajax({
      type     : 'POST',
      url      : '/update_profile_picture', 
      dataType : 'script',
      data     :  { picid:picid, callsign:callsign, page_name:page_name }
    });
    alert("Goodbye.");
  };
</script>
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'update_profile_picture', to: 'picturethings#update_profile', as: :update_profile_picture
```

I can see from the browser console that the ajax request is not firing, nothing happens. The "Hello" alert appears, so the code is executing at least that far, but falls over during the ajax bit. The "Goodbye" alert never appears.

Comment: Did you check your server log as well if the request is being made or not?

Comment: is `page_name ` and `callsign` defined?

Comment: Aargh that was it! page_name was not defined. Stupid.

Comment: If the "Goodbye" alert is not shown that probably means there is a mistake in the ajax call, but I honestly cannot see any mistakes. The only thing that comes to my mind is the absence of a jQuery inclusion, since $.ajax is a jQuery method. Check it out in the web inspector, that is probably the reason is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment in the question, your `ajax` looks fine... Just make sure you have defined `page_name` and `callsign`:

```
function set_profile(picid) {
  alert("Hello.");
  $.ajax({
    type     : 'POST',
    url      : '/update_profile_picture', 
    dataType : 'script',
    data     :  { picid:picid, callsign:callsign, page_name:page_name }
  });
  alert("Goodbye.");
};
```